# How to ask for the already promised raise

Tags: salary, new-job

I have worked for company A for about 3 years. Then, there was some internal & financial problems, and I thought is time to moving on.

I signed with company B, I was very impressed by their conditions and all the overal aspects. Before signing the contract, I was given a letter ( from the company B ) where there was specified my career plan and also the remuneration / part based on my performances / certifications / exams and so on. For example, if I'll pass 2 exams/certifications a salary raise will be given.

I already passed one exam, and next week I will have the next one, which I hope I'll be passing too. If all things go well, being the end of the month, should I remind them by email and ask them politely if I will receive the mentioned raise or just to wait for the pay day and have confidence on that letter.

Considering the fact that I'm working here just for a couple months, I don't want to be seen as rude or greedy for money

Comment: If you're in any position to request an employee-evaluation meeting, I'd recommend you do so. You'll get (hopefully) honest feedback about how much they value you, what they wish you'd do different etc. And pretty sure your certifications will come up, giving you the perfect opening.

Comment: Do you have any reason not to have confidence in the letter? You've only been there a couple months. They haven't even gotten a chance to honor their end of the bargain and you're already expecting them to let you down. This question (and your obvious expectation of disappointment) make you look rude and greedy for money.

Answer (score 8):

The way I usually go about these things is very passively. If you are too aggressive about it, you will come off as greedy for money or possibly rude, depending.

Instead of saying something like

> "Don't forget - If I pass this exam, I should get a raise."

Try something like this:

> "A while back I got an email saying if I passed both exams I would get a raise, is that still the case or no?"

This will let your boss know you aren't necessarily *greedy*, but rather just curious and hopeful, which will hopefully be rewarded.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Unless they are funding your studies, they can't know if you've passed the exams, which means you have to tell them. That sounds like the ideal time to ask for the raise they promised. You can do this politely by asking them if there's any paperwork you need to supply them with. That will remind them of their promise and give everyone the opportunity to take care of any details.

If you want to confirm that the offer still stands *before* you pass your exam, you can ask your manager exactly that. It's not greedy at all.

Answer (score 2):

The company has to live up to its agreement. Nothing to do with greed, unless you are feeling greedy - But only you would know for sure whether you are feeling greedy.

Let them know that the ball is in their court right after you can substantiate that you passed the second exam. While passing your second exam has money ramifications for you, it also has ramifications for the company, which is why they gave you  the incentive. And now, it's incumbent on them that they have to live up to their part of the deal.

Answer (score 1):

Verify whether the letter also specifies **when** this salary increase will happen. More often than not, salary is only adjusted once per year, even if you hit your targets sooner.

Answer (score 1):

If you received a **Letter**, then the company should keep the promise and give you the expected raise, as soon as, the condition is met(*if I'll pass 2 exams/certifications a salary raise will be given*), without any need to remind them and normally the raise will be given in the next promised **annual performance review** which is described in the contract.

**But** if they haven't considered it or talk about it, this is here where you should point it out, for example:

> Sir, I whould like to mention the fact that you promised me a raise
>   if I pass 2 exams/certifications, and I whould like to know when
>   can I benifit from it now I've passed the two Exams.