# My salary hasn't raised after trial period as it was promised during interview

Tags: salary, raise

During interview at my current job my boss have told me that, if my trial period (3 months long) will be fine, I'll get a further contract including a pay rise. During this trial I've proven my skills, ability to solve problems and developed good stuff, as my boss have mentioned.

I've received this new contract today just a few minutes before going home, and my boss have told me to check if everything there's ok, as he just used previous document (trial contract) to apply some changes on it. As I was in a hurry I've said that I'll check it at home. When I got home I've readen this contract and noticed that although every other parts are correct, the salary part hasn't changed. I've got some mixed feelings about that.

Assuming that my boss have forgotten about salary raise part, what should I do, and how should I act to get this raise as it was promised during my interview?

Comment: Do you have this promised raise in writing, or was it just verbal?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: "[Should I talk with my boss for a promised raise?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/86201/should-i-talk-with-my-boss-for-a-promised-raise)", "[How to ask for the already promised raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/43202/how-to-ask-for-the-already-promised-raise)", "[raises promised in offer letter not given](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/105132/raises-promised-in-offer-letter-not-given)"

Comment: It was verbal, but words should have the same meaning in terms of gentlemen's agreement

Comment: @ArturS Sure, it would be great if this is just an oversight and your boss sticks to his word, but if you have that promise in writing then it becomes a *legal* agreement that your boss is required to follow.

Comment: @ArturS Unfortunately, gentleman's agreements aren't exactly what you'd call enforceable.

Comment: This smells.  It doesn't seem likely that the boss would have whipped up a quick contract and handed it over.  My guess is that the boss was hoping you'd missed the lack of salary increase.  The good news is that you haven't forgotten it, so you can talk to your boss about it and it will likely be fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Assuming that my boss have forgotten about salary raise part, what
>   should I do, and how should I act to get this raise as it was promised
>   during my interview?

Bring the contract with you to work tomorrow. Ask to talk with your boss. Point out that you were expecting the salary to be increased from what it was during your trial period.

Act as if it were a simple oversight that needs to be corrected. Then see where the conversation goes from there.

Comment: Looks like a quite smart way to treat it like an oversight. I hope it'll work well

Comment: Then they will probably tell you something about no room in the budget or will see at your review... be prepared for that

Comment: I hope it won't happen

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - worked like a charm :D